# Unable to get one specific input from scanner

Tags: java

I am a newbie. I know that my code is messy. I will be working on adding the comments and such.

```
    try // get customer's address
    {
    System.out.println("\nPlease type in your shipping address.");
    System.out.println ("This way you can receive what you have ordered.");
    System.out.println ("In this format: Street, City, State, Zipcode\n");
    customerAddress = input.nextLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("You need to enter in an address.");
            }

    try // get customer's telephone number
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter in your telephone number:\n");
        phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("You need to enter in a phone number.");
    }
```

I am able to get an input from the phoneNumber but the program seems to skip right over the customerAddress input.

Below is what I get in the command prompt. Notice that I was able to input data under the telephone number, but did not get the chance to put it in the address section.

> Please type in your shipping address.
>   This way you can receive what you have ordered.
>   In this format: Street, City, State, Zipcode
>
> Please enter in your telephone number:
>
> 123457890

Are there any logic errors that could be causing it to skip over?

Comment: Are you reading in any numbers before this? If so, just add input.nextLine(); on its own line right before phoneNumber = input.nextLine();

Comment: Accept above comment as an Answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading more data, with Scaner like `input.nextInt();` then it will read only one int.
One solution is that add `input.nextLine();` and it should probably work.

### Solution 2:

Use `BufferedReader;`

```
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try{
            System.out.println("\nPlease type in your shipping address.");
            System.out.println ("This way you can receive what you have ordered.");
            System.out.println ("In this format: Street, City, State, Zipcode\n");

            customerAddress = bufferRead.readLine();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("You need to enter in an address.");
        }

        try {
             System.out.println("Please enter in your telephone number:\n");
             phoneNumber =  bufferRead.readLine();
        }catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println("You need to enter in a phone number.");
        }  


        System.out.println(customerAddress + " " + phoneNumber);
```

See if you get the output with the BufferedReader.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of other things that weren't shown in your post could be causing a stray new line to remain on the buffer. A more robust option is to loop while nextLine returns an empty string.